# Getting values to compare from 2 very different classes

Tags: java, arraylist, polymorphism, parent-child, iteration

I have these two classes, Bullet and EnemyJet. The Bullet class extends the Player class and the EnemyJet class extends an EnemyControl class. They are both using an arraylist which I'm trying to store and get their positions from.

```
    public class Player extends Mob {
    public List<Bullet> bullets = new ArrayList<Bullet>();

    }

    public class EnemyControl extends Mob {
    public List<EnemyJet> enemyJet = new ArrayList<EnemyJet>();

    }
```

Would I need to make a new class to store and test the two positions, or maybe use the Mob class they extend? How would I get the same values from the lists to compare them inside the new class?

For example, test for a collision with the bullet and the enemy jet. If so,remove the jet.

EnemyJet Class:

```
public class EnemyJet extends EnemyControl{

Random rdm = new Random();

private int destx, desty;
private Sprite sprite;
private int counter = 0;
private boolean dead = false;
private boolean setPos = false;

private void newPosition(){
    destx = rdm.nextInt(963);
    desty = rdm.nextInt(500);
    //System.out.println(destx + " " + desty);
}

private void move(){
    if(x > destx) x-=3;
    if(y > desty) y-=3;
    if(x < destx) x+=3;
    if(y < desty) y+=3;

//  if(x >= )
}

private void setPos(){
    if(!setPos){
        x = rdm.nextInt(500);
        y = rdm.nextInt(100);
        setPos = true;
    }
}

public void update(){
    setPos();
    move();

    if(counter > rdm.nextInt(20000)){
    newPosition();
    counter = 0;
    }
    counter++;
}

public void render(Screen screen){
    sprite = Sprite.enemyjet;
    screen.renderMob(x, y, sprite);
}
}
```

Bullet Class:

```
public class Bullet {
private Sprite sprite;
private boolean removed = false;
public int y = 0, x = 0;

public Bullet(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public boolean isRemoved(){
    return removed;
}

public void update(){
    y -= 15;
}

public void render(Screen screen){
    sprite = Sprite.jetbullet;
    screen.drawBullet(x, y, sprite);
}
}
```

Player Class:

```
public class Player extends Mob {
public List<Bullet> bullets = new ArrayList<Bullet>();

private Keyboard input;
private Sprite sprite;

private int counter = 0;
private int fireRate = 4;

public Player(Keyboard input){
    this.input = input;
}

public void update(){
    int xa = 0, ya = 0;

    if(input.up) ya=-7;
    if(input.down) ya =+7;
    if(input.left) xa=-7;
    if(input.right) xa=+7;

    if(!input.up && !input.down && !input.left && !input.right)
        intensity = 0; else intensity = 8;

    move(xa, ya);

    if(input.shoot && counter > fireRate){
        bullet = new Bullet(x, y);
        bullets.add(bullet);
        counter = 0;
    }

    if(bullets.size() > 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++){
            bullets.get(i).update();
            if(bullets.get(i).y < 0){
                bullets.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }   
    counter++;
}

public void render(Screen screen){
    sprite = Sprite.jet;

    if(bullets.size()>0)
    for(int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++){
        bullets.get(i).render(screen);
    }

    screen.renderMob(x, y, sprite);

    screen.setIntensity(intensity);
}

}
```

Added all classes Player, EnemyJet and Bullet.

Comment: Please post `Bullet` and `EnemyJet`. Your `Mob` and sub-classes should be irrelevant at this point, the first two should have `Position`.

Comment: "The Bullet class extends the Player class and the EnemyJet class extends an EnemyControl class" - can you show this?  It seems very odd to me that `Bullet` would extend `Player`.  But if that's true, then any public methods that you've defined for a `Mob` should be able to be called on a `Bullet` or an `EnemyJet`.

Comment: It makes sense if your using the Bullet as a Player attribute. Because isn't the Bullet used by the Player? I can see how this restricts the Bullet from being accessed by EnemyControl as it is only a Player attribute. I'll tidy up my code and post it soon as.

Comment: Yes, Bullet can be a Player attribute, since Players can have Bullets, but there's no way that Bullet should be a Player subclass. I have to agree, not only does that not make sense, it is batchit crazy.

Comment: Player uses bullets like a Player uses its position to tell the bullets where to start from. What doesn't seem to make sense? Ok, I'm sorry I just realized I'm extending it my bad...

Comment: Because it completely fails the "is-a" test. Just like a Lion passes the "is-a" test for Carnivore, since it is a specialized version of a Carnivore, while Teeth do not. A lion would use teeth via **composition** not inheritance -- a Tooth is not a sub-type of lion, is it? Similarly a Bullet is not a more specialized version of a Person. A person could use Bullets via composition but not inheritance. It really really really doesn't make sense to do what you're doing. You must ask yourself why you'd even want Bullet to extend Person -- what purpose would it achieve? If it does achieve a purpose

Comment: ... then your code's design is wrong.

Comment: Likewise, Player should not extend Mob. In fact a Mob would be likely some collection of Person objects. I would also get all UI code out of my foundation/model classes. For instance Player should not have a Keyboard field. I think you need to re-design your entire program from the ground up. This is heading towards heartbreak.

Comment: Thanks this has all been very helpful. There isn't much to redesign in that area. As I've only just started to use more polymorphism to cope with the entitys such as player, enemy, bullets etc. This is good thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could go through all bullets and check if they have the same position as the enemyjet and implement a method in Mob that compares them if you will use the comparison repeatedly. Or you just do the compare yourself in your driver class that controls both during runtime, e.g. the main() or where the events are caught and synchronized and presented on screen.

Comment: I've done some testing. After I do some redesign, I'm sure I can go with this thanks.